# python regular expressions -- split on non-word char or consecutive dashes, but not on single dash

Tags: python, regex

I wish to split a sentence into a list of words on non-word characters (excluding dash, which likely means a hyphen) and consecutive dashes. What I mean is: "merry-go-round" is one word, not three words; "condition--but" is two words: remove the consecutive dashes.

I tried the following and it doesn't work:
`listofwords = [word for word in re.split('[^a-zA-Z0-9]|-{2,}',sentence)]`

I can provide a sample sentence:
`sentence = 'sample sentence---such as well-being {\t'`
and the desired result is ['sample', 'sentence', 'such', 'as', 'well-being'].

Comment: [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) is a good regex testing tool

Comment: Might be able to split on this `-{2,}|\s`.

Comment: You could do it in two passes: First, replace `---*` with a space, then split normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\w+(?:-\w+)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zF8bQ1/1)

**Code:**

```
p = re.compile(r'\w+(?:-\w+)*')
test_str = "sample sentence---such as well-being {   "

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

**Output:**

```
['sample', 'sentence', 'such', 'as', 'well-being']
```